# Why do I have to use the optional "?" in this code?

Tags: swift

Why can't I just write " var response: String "without optional "?" in program below on the 3rd line?

```
class SurveyQuestion {
   var text: String
   var response: String? //here
  init(text: String) {
      self.text = text
  } 
  func ask() {
    print(text)
  }
}
let cheeseQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "Do you like cheese?")
cheeseQuestion.ask()
// Prints "Do you like cheese?"
cheeseQuestion.response = "Yes, I do like cheese."
```

Comment: What keeps you from doing that? Any error message?

Comment: you can make it non-optional, but then you need to provide an initial value

Comment: Because [***Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created***](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

Comment: If you don't put "?", what's the compiler error message exactly? It should give you hint on why (initial value). Ie, what's the default value? It can't be "nil" since it's not an optional. Maybe a default value to `""`? It might work then, but is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what you would get if you try to access the `response` before you assign it:

```
let cheeseQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "Do you like cheese?")
print(cheeseQuestion.response) // what would this print?
```

It's gotta be some kind of a value, right? The value that makes the most sense is something that represents "this question has *no* response yet", which is what `nil` is - the absence of a value. Making `response` optional has the side effect of making its default value `nil`.

If you don't want it to be optional, that's fine too, but you have to give it a default value (not `nil`, only optionals can have `nil` as a value!)

```
class SurveyQuestion {
    var text: String
    var response: String = "some default response"
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

or you can initialise it in the initialiser:

```
init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
    self.response = "some default response"
}
```

or you can add a parameter to the initialiser and initialise it to that:

```
init(text: String, response: String) {
    self.text = text
    self.response = response
}
```

Essentially, if `response` is not optional, it needs to have *some value* that is not `nil` when its initialiser finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want optional, then provide a initial value to that variable.

example:-  `var response: String = "ABC"`